# mySQL returning different row from calculated value

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

```
SELECT table1.id, (SELECT MIN(SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( latitude - table1.lat ) , 
2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( table1.lon - longitude ) * COS( latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) 
)) from table2 limit 1) AS distance FROM table1
```

The result itself seems correct, however I actually want the query to return table2.id based on the calculated value instead. How can I achieve that?

`table1 contains id, lat, lon`

`table2 contains id, latitude, longitude`

I do need to get the smallest distance's ID(table2.id) for each row in table1 using the data in table2.

Comment: how table1 and table 2 are related .. ?

Comment: Just by calculation. Two tables containing latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: and then how these tables are related ??? show a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: `table1 contains id, lat, lon. table2 contains id, latitude, longitude` I do need to get the smallest distance's ID(table2.id) for each row in table1 using the data in table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.id, (SELECT table2.id from table2 order by (SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( 
latitude - table1.lat ) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( table1.lon - longitude ) * COS( 
latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) )) limit 0,1 ) as table2_id FROM table1
```